# Is there a way of knowing if data is being piped into a express response?

Tags: express, stream

if I have a `Readable` stream, I can pipe it to response like this:

```
app.use(function(req, res) {
  stream.pipe(res);
});
```

1. If I didn't have this code in front of me, but I did have access to the `res` object, is there a way of knowing that something is being piped into it? and knowing when it finishes?
2. I noticed I can still use `res.send()` and `res.end()` while something is being piped, what happens to the response then? Are there rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There exists a `pipe` event for *writeable* streams:

   > The `'pipe'` event is emitted when the stream.pipe() method is called on a readable stream, adding this writable to its set of destinations.

   so I think the following could work:

-

```
export async function myHandler(req, res) {
    const reader = getReadableStreamSomehow();

    res.on('pipe', src => {
        console.log('Something is piping into the response');
        assert.equal(src, reader);
    });

    reader.pipe(res);
}
```

Ref: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_pipe

2. Can't say exactly, but you'll likely run into unexpected side affects. `res.send()` ultimately calls `res.end()` as shown [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/dc538f6e810bd462c98ee7e6aae24c64d4b1da93/lib/response.js#L216). Since `res` is a stream, my best guess is that it depends. You could have multiple items writing/piping to `res`, but A maybe finish before B so B's content will likely replace A's content and vice versa.

Comment: very nice, thanks! The problem was the some middleware piped something into the response, but other handlers ran also and tried to send more data. I wonder if it's a good practice to prevent `send()` and `end()` after detecting something being piped in. But it seems like there would be no way to prevent something calling `.pipe()` twice?